# How to put a ~ (tilde) UNDER vectors i and j

Tags: vector

Can anyone please how me an easy way to place a tilde (~) UNDER vector that is expressed in terms  of i, j and k.

I have seen the package **undertilde** mentioned, found at this link:

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/undertilde

but have no idea how to install this package on my Macbook Air.  Yes, I have read the documentation and it does seem to indicate where to place the unzipped files.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an ordinary TeX installation on your Mac, you almost certainly already have the `undertilde` package available. Have you tried `\usepackage{undertilde}` in your preamble to load it?

So assuming you don't have it:

TeX on the Mac is going to be one of two distributions. MikTeX (less common) will automatically install `undertilde` if it's not already present. You'll get a bunch of messages saying it's being downloaded and assuming you have a working internet connection it will be in place and you can continue to use `undertilde` as mentioned.

If you have a TeXlive-based distribution and it's not showing up, you can try, at a command line, typing

```
 tlmgr install undertilde
```

If you get a message "Remote repository newer than local" it means that it's time to upgrade (reinstall) your TeX installation (TeXlive likes to do a clean re-install on an annual basis). Go to https://www.tug.org/mactex/ for the link to re-install (unless you're using the TinyTeX distribution, in which case follow the instructions at https://yihui.org/tinytex/).

In general, manually installing packages from source is never necessary with modern TeX distributions.

Finally, I would recommend using the package `accents` to get the `\undertilde` command rather than `undertilde` since (a) it provides a number of useful accents that you might find yourself needing and (2) `undertilde` has not been updated in over 20 years (not necessarily a bad thing given the stability of the LaTeX ecosystem) and you might find more support for using `accents` among other LaTeX users (which is definitely a good thing).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation Ron.  I am running Texlive on my Macbook Air 2020.  tried the command:  tlmgr install undertilde, however received the message Package undertilde not present in repository, an error has occurred.  As for the accents package, I tried \usepackage{accents}, but my It gave me errors in my original code.  Once I remove the package declaration - my code compiles.

Comment: @Stephan I'd be really surprised if you needed to do anything to install the package. TeXlive will generally have everything pre-installed.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to be installed.  I'm using TexStudio as my editor and it does not appear in the pulldown options, as do other packages.

Comment: Don..... all working as expected now.  I can use the accents package now without compile errors.  Thank you so much for your time and effort.